# Dropdownlist Error

Tags: c#

In .net win form application. I load dropdownlist like this.

```
 private void loadChannelCombo()
        {
            string sql = "select channelID,channelName from rechannel where isActive=1 order by channelName";
            DataTable dt = DBHandler.GetData(sql);
            ddlChannel.DataSource = dt;
            ddlChannel.DisplayMember = "channelName";
            ddlChannel.ValueMember = "channelID";
        }
```

now I want to do same in .net web aaplication. When I copy paste that code error occurred like
[image]

I want to do same as in web application. How can I Do that????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in asp.net datatextfield and datavaluefield are the exact alternatives for displaymember and valuemember. Use them!

Comment: hmm, but Andrei just posted the relevant links too, so +1 for him too :)